# VS2010 VB.NET XML Comments for class field not showing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, comments

In VB.NET project in VS2010 I try to add XML comments (''') to fields of class. There is a problem with displaying comments: only full comments for class methods are displayed, when I placed mouse cursor over members names in Main() sub.

In project compile options "Generate XML documentation file" checkbox is turned on; full comments are normally displayed in intellisense list (when I type period after object name).

Is that by design or can be changed in preferences?

[image]

Minimal code sample placed below.

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Test class
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class TestClass

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Test field
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public s As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Test method
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub Method()

    End Sub

End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim c = New TestClass() ' "Class TestClass \ Test class" displayed
    c.s = "abc"             ' Only "Public s As String" displayed!
    c.Method()              ' "Public s As String \ Test method" displayed
End Sub
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Everything is working as expected - what's the problem?

Comment: I've attached image to clarify issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that XML comments don't show up when you hover on fields. If you change

```
Public s As String
```

to this:

```
Public Property s As String
```

It will work. Generally, you should not expose variables directly through `Public` and use properties instead. You will get better integration into .NET this way (such as DataBinding).

Looks like this problem is specific to VB, because C# counterpart works with no issues:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test class
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test field
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public String s;

    /// <summary>
    /// Test method
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public void Method() {}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass c = new TestClass();
        c.s = "abc"; //not a property, but help shows on hover
        c.Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I discovered. I am engaged supporting one VB.NET project (not mine) and begin to tidy up code, starting from adding comments. This behavior of VB.NET seems to be "by design", but it is not completely clear. I will think about changing variables to properties.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Fixed in VS 2012; VB.Net shows summary for fields, now.